# Изменение title сайта на bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Искал почти везде, вот head в шаблоне, как я понимаю куда-то ссылается?

```html
<head>

<?$APPLICATION->ShowMeta("keywords_prop", "keywords")?>
<?$APPLICATION->ShowMeta("description_prop", "description")?>
<?$APPLICATION->ShowHead();?>
<meta content="IE=EmulateIE7" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<title><?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle()?></title>
<?
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript('/bitrix/templates/web20/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript('/bitrix/templates/web20/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript('/bitrix/templates/web20/js/jquery-galleryview-1.0.1/jquery.galleryview-1.0.1-pack.js');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript('/bitrix/templates/web20/js/jquery-galleryview-1.0.1/jquery.timers-1.1.2.js');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript('/bitrix/templates/web20/js/swfobject.js');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript('/bitrix/templates/web20/js/script.js');
?>
</head>
```

Comment: Вы читали курс ["Контент-менеджер"](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=1850&LESSON_PATH=3905.4461.1850) по установке заголовков? А [документацию](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/showtitle.php) просмотрели? Что именно у Вас не получается при смене? Какие действия выполняли? Что хотите получить?

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы уже ответили на мой вопрос!

Comment: Тогда я оформлю комментарий как ответ, надеюсь вы отметите его как решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос по изменению заголовка, а также других свойств страницы вы можете найти в курсе "[Контент-менеджер](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34)" в главе "[Управление свойствами страниц и разделов](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=1850&LESSON_PATH=3905.4461.1850)".

Подробнее о функции `ShowTitle()` можете прочесть в [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/showtitle.php).

Answer (score 0):

На странице нужно установить заголовок:

```
<?
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Page title");
?>
```

[Подробнее](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/settitle.php)

[Подробнее про технологию как работает](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3489&LESSON_PATH=3913.4619.3489)

Comment: Спасибо уже решили вопрос!